# Ruby 2.0.0 String#Match ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

I see this a lot and haven't figured out a graceful solution. If user input contains invalid byte sequences, I need to be able to have it not raise an exception.  For example:

```
# @raw_response comes from user and contains invalid UTF-8
# for example: @raw_response = "\xBF"  
regex.match(@raw_response)
ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
```

Numerous similar questions have been asked and the result appears to be encoding or force encoding the string.  Neither of these work for me however:

```
regex.match(@raw_response.force_encoding("UTF-8"))
ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
```

or

```
regex.match(@raw_response.encode("UTF-8", :invalid=>:replace, :replace=>"?"))
ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
```

Is this a bug with Ruby 2.0.0 or am I missing something?

What is strange is it appear to be encoding correctly, but match continues to raise an exception:

```
@raw_response.encode("UTF-8", :invalid=>:replace, :replace=>"?").encoding
 => #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You tag this as ruby-on-rails, but normally any rails form will post utf-8 to the server. How does your form look? Or what is the origin of your strings.

Comment: This happens several different ways in our app: user agent strings and meta information on files.

Comment: mdesantis sure, just use any invalid string: @raw_response = "\xBF"

Comment: Same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11375342/stringencode-not-fixing-invalid-byte-sequence-in-utf-8-error

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In Ruby 2.0 the [`encode` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-encode) is a no-op when encoding a string to its current encoding:

> Please note that conversion from an encoding `enc` to the same encoding `enc` is a no-op, i.e. the receiver is returned without any changes, and no exceptions are raised, even if there are invalid bytes.

This changed in 2.1, which also added the [`scrub` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-scrub) as an easier way to do this.

If you are unable to upgrade to 2.1, you’ll have to encode into a different encoding and back in order to remove invalid bytes, something like:

```
if ! s.valid_encoding?
  s = s.encode("UTF-16be", :invalid=>:replace, :replace=>"?").encode('UTF-8')
end
```

Comment: Thanks @matt, thats exactly what I needed! A bit of a hack, but I'll take it.

Comment: @matt thank you! It can be any encoding, not exactly UTF-16be? How should I choose one?

Answer (score 11):

Since you're using Rails and not just Ruby you can also use [tidy_bytes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Multibyte/Chars.html#method-i-tidy_bytes). This works with Ruby 2.0 and also will probably give you back sensible data instead of just replacement characters.

Comment: I feel compelled to give you a big belated thank you. Knowing about "tidy_bytes" earlier would've saved me many hours of frustration...can't believe I hadn't heard of it until just now.

Comment: `tidy_bytes` is amazing! I wish I knew about it earlier too lol.