# Ruby encoding to utf-8

Tags: ruby, encoding, utf-8

I have a string like this, and i'm having issues encoding it to UTF-8 :

```
"únicos do brazil"
```

I get: `"\xFA" on US-ASCII` as message of an `Encoding::InvalidByteSequenceError` for char `ú`
when using: `string.encode('UTF-8')` 
How can i successfully encode `\xFA` to UTF-8?
Thx

Comment: What is your ruby version?

Comment: i think you answer should be here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Encoding.html

Comment: Solved by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11375342/stringencode-not-fixing-invalid-byte-sequence-in-utf-8-error